# Python: get_time Time interval

Tags: python, glfw

I'm trying to make a short loop animation that rotates the object between 0~90 degrees iteratively.

```
T = glfw.get_time()-animStartTime;

#v is the rotation vector 
r = T * v
```

i.e.) 0->10->20->...->90->80->70->...->0->10...so on

I need to set time interval as (0 <= T <= 1)to rotate 0~90 degree; however, since I used glfw.time_get()for time elasping, it rotates the object 360 degree.

Is there any way to set interval to the glfw.time_get() ??

Comment: Save the time each time you rotate your object then substract the new (current) time by the saved one

Comment: I think that's what I did on the first line, T = glfw.get_time()-animStartTime;.  But it keeps rotating 360 degree

Comment: I don't know how you defined it and you need to redefine animStartTime each time you rotate your object